Using average, offset & match together
I'm creating a fitness tracker with daily inputs & a weekly summary on a dashboard. My daily input data looks like this:



Date
Miles
Intake




01-Dec-24
11
3130


02-Dec-24
0
2730


03-Dec-24
8
2930


04-Dec-24
12
3130



And so on. I've managed to export data from Garmin Connect and it now goes back every day for years. I want the dashboard to provide a sum of mileage and an average of intake for every 7 days. For example:



Week commencing
Total miles
Average intake




25-Nov-24
45
3130


02-Dec-24
50
3250


09-Dec-24
35
2840


16-Dec-24
45
3130



I've been trying to use a match from the 'week commencing' column in the dashboard table to identify the first day of the week in the 'date' column/source data table. Then sum/average the 7 days from that date as necessary, and put in an offset to move the reference in the source data table down 7 rows for each row the formula moves down in the dashboard table. But no luck quite yet! I hope the information provided is enough to picture what I'm going for, but I'm happy to provide a more comprehensive example of my data & desired dashboard table if required.

I'd look into the GROUPBY() function for this. Add a column called 'Week commencing' first to get the correct grouping. Then you can HSTACK() both SUM() and AVERAGE() in there.

Imagine the following data:

Columns B:D are static values from your Garmin.
In A2:
=DROP(TOCOL(B:B,1),1)-WEEKDAY(+DROP(TOCOL(B:B,1),1),2)+1

In F2:
=GROUPBY(A.:.A;B.:.C,HSTACK(SUM,AVERAGE),1,0)


The data wasn't exactly as detailed in my question, it was a very simplified example. So, this wasn't the exact solution. Nevertheless, these functions are new to me so I enjoyed the trial & error tweaks to finally get there myself. Many thanks!
May I ask, though - what purpose does it serve to use the A.:.A reference rather than A:A?

With simple Excel functions:
Formula in B39
=SUMIFS(B$25:B$28,A$25:A$28,">="&A39,A$25:A$28,"<"&A39+7)
Formula in C39
=SUMIFS(C$25:C$28,A$25:A$28,">="&A39,A$25:A$28,"<"&A39+7)/COUNTIFS(A$25:A$28,">="&A39,A$25:A$28,"<"&A39+7)
and drag down both.
Without SUMIFS
B39: =SUM(IF(((A$25:A$28>=A39)*(A$25:A$28<A39+7))=1,B$25:B$28))
C39: =SUM(IF(((A$25:A$28>=A39)*(A$25:A$28<A39+7))=1,C$25:C$28))/COUNT(IF(((A$25:A$28>=A39)*(A$25:A$28<A39+7))=1,A$25:A$28))

